# Using geom_point to change colors and title of legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made this map using...

[image: my map with wonky title and colors not representative of species]

```
ilwi2<-ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = w,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "lightyellow", colour = "black") +
  coord_map() +
  geom_point(data = gent,
             aes(x = long2, y = lat2,
                 fill = acceptedScientificName,
                 colour = acceptedScientificName),
             shape =21)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank())
```

I am pretty happy with how it looks butI would like to change the title (acceptedScientificName) to "Species occurrences in Illinois and Wisconsin from GBIF" and the colors of each species. I would like for Gentiana andrewsii Griseb. to be seagreen and Gentiana puberulenta J.S.Pringle to be royalblue3. Please let me know if you have any suggestions! I would appreciate simple answers that jive with this code I have already because I am new to R.

Comment: add `labs(color = "Species occurrences in Illinois and Wisconsin from GBIF")` and `scale_colour_manual(values = c("Gentiana andrewsii Griseb." = "seagreen", "Gentiana puberulenta J.S.Pringle" = "royalblue3"))`